# Cocoa editable text with no input box

Tags: macos, cocoa

I am trying to make an editable text object in cocoa that contains no input box (just the text).  I have tried doing this using NSTextField but setDrawsBackground: NO and setBordered: no have not helped.  Is there another method for NSTextField that will do this or do I need to use another class?  I looked at NSText but this class seems to just be the same as NSTextField with less functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're headed in the right direction. Are you missing [`- setBezeled:`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTextField_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSTextField/setBezeled:)`NO`?

It's fairly simple to get what you're looking for through Interface Builder.  The only changes required (from its default instance) are to set the border to the dashed (invisible) option and uncheck the Draws Background.